# macro to find specific text in row and copy to cell in same row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook and what i am trying to do is find the word "holiday" in a row between B and G and place the word "holiday" in a cell in the same row in column A, I've attached a pic of the sheet, I need to ignore the cells that contain "Rest" and just put "holiday" in cells that contain "Yes"

[image: Holiday Planner]

```
Sub dural()
    Dim AB As Range, r As Range, K As Long
     Set AB = Range("B:G").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    K = 1
        For Each r In AB
        If InStr(1, r.Value, "holiday") > 0 Then
        r.Copy Cells(K, "A")
        K = K + 1
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I found this code elsewhere on the site but what it does is puts "holiday" in column A from row 1 down by the number of times it finds "holiday"

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't trust code you find on the web that's indented like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also create a **For loop** to do this task:

```
Sub Holiday()

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Yes" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf("B" & i & ":G" & i, "holiday") > 0 Then
                    Cells(i, 1).Value = "holiday"
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Since you also include color coding in your example, I have added a line that will also change the color of your cell to green.

Comment: This nearly works, when i run it though it puts "holiday" in every cell that contains "Yes" and not just the cells where "holiday" is in that specific row.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I believe that you are looking for something like this:

```
Sub dural()

Dim AB As Range, r As Range
Set AB = Range("B:G").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each r In AB
    If InStr(1, LCase(r.Value), "holiday") > 0 And _
        LCase(Cells(r.Row, "A").Value) = "yes" Then
            r.Copy Destination:=Cells(r.Row, "A")
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: This also nearly works but puts "holiday" in a cell whether it contains "Yes" or "Rest". I need it to ignore cells containing "Rest"

Comment: Just added the additional condition of having `yes` in that particular row in column `A`. Is this now working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that column H is empty:

```
[H2:H37] = "=IF(AND(A2=""Yes"",COUNTIF(B2:G2,""holiday"")),""holiday"",A2)"
[A2:A37] = [H2:H37].Value2
[H2:H37] = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not exactly short of solutions, but here goes anyway. This uses Find

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, s As String

With Range("B2", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="holiday", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        s = rFind.Address
        Do
            If Cells(rFind.Row, 1).Value = "Yes" Then
                Cells(rFind.Row, 1).Value = "holiday"
            End If
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
        Loop While rFind.Address <> s
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works a treat. The number of different solutions to my question really amazes me. Thank You to each and everyone of you that has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub holiday()

Dim cell As Range

 For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:D").cells
        If c.Value = "holiday" Then
            Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(c.Row, 1)
                curCell.Value = "holiday"
        End If

Next

End Sub
```

Change parameters as you wish... I suggest to use specific range instead of global range... B1:G10 instead B:G for performance purposes